# Relationship between eigenvectors of a covariance matrix and its component covariance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

I have a covariance matrix $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$. I then divide the matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that has $N$ rows into $n$ portions $\mathbf{x_i} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ each having $N_i$ rows such that:

$$
\mathbf{X} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x_1} \\
\mathbf{x_2} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $N = \sum_{i=1}^{n} N_i$.

I compute covariance matrices on each portion so that in general we have:

$$
\mathbf{S_i} = \mathbf{x_i}^T \mathbf{x_i}
$$

I noticed that:

$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{S_1} + \mathbf{S_2} + \dots + \mathbf{S_n}
$$

since:

$$
s_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} x_{ik} x_{kj} = \sum_{\substack{k=1\\k \in (1)}}^{N_1} x^{(1)}_{ik} x^{(1)}_{kj} + \sum_{\substack{k=1\\k \in (2)}}^{N_2} x^{(2)}_{ik} x^{(2)}_{kj} + \dots + \sum_{\substack{k=1\\k \in (n)}}^{N_n} x^{(n)}_{ik} x^{(n)}_{kj}
$$

where $x_{ij}$ are elements of $\mathbf{X}$ and $x_{ij}^{(p)}$ are elements of $\mathbf{x_p}$.

I call each $\mathbf{S_i}$ a *component* covariance matrix.

Suppose I find the eigenvectors of each component covariance matrix $\mathbf{S_i}$. Are there known theorems that can help me find out a relationship between the eigenvectors of all $\mathbf{S_i}$ and the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{S}$?

For the moment, it only seems intuitive to me to think that such relation should exist, since the component matrices are computed on portions of $\mathbf{X}$ and the information about each portion $\mathbf{x_i}$ is as well contained in $\mathbf{X}$. So perhaps eigenvectors of $\mathbf{S}$ would be as well "informed" by the eigenvectors of all $\mathbf{S_i}$?

Comment: I understand that each $S_i$ is a covariance matrix, and that $S = S_1 + \cdots + S_n$. Is there any other connection between $S$ and the $S_i$ that is implied by the term "component covariance matrix"?

Comment: Hi, no, I called them *component* just because they sum up to $\mathbf{S}$.

Comment: Then there isn't much that you can say about the eigenvectors of $S$. At best, I suspect that if the eigenvector sets of the $S_i$ are "nearly the same" and the eigenvalues of the $S_i$ are also known, then there might be a useful inequality regarding the eigenvectors of $S$.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for your comment. I would intuitively suspect that there should be a link since information about every $\mathbf{S_i}$ is within $\mathbf{S}$. When you say useful inequality do you know a specific theorem that can help?

Comment: There are some relevant results in section VII.3.2 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis.* In particular: for the case of $n=2$, we have a bound on the "distance" between the eigenvectors of $S$ and the eigenvectors of $S_1$ that depends on $S_2$.

Comment: I updated my question since I realized that I made it too general. I have in fact a very specific use-case that I now described which answers your first question.

Comment: It's trivial to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the $S_i$ in your case, but finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S = X^TX$ is not. Note that any solution to your problem would provide a solution to the general problem of finding the SVD of a given matrix $X$.